# Removing multiple columns from R data.table with parameter for columns to remove

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to manipulate a number of data.tables in similar ways, and would like to write a function to accomplish this.  I would like to pass in a parameter containing a list of columns that would have the operations performed.  This works fine when the vector declaration of columns is the left hand side of the := operator, but not if it is declared earlier (or passed into the function).  The follow code shows the issue.

```
dt = data.table(a = letters, b = 1:2, c=1:13)
colsToDelete = c('b', 'c')
dt[,colsToDelete := NULL] # doesn't work but I don't understand why not.
dt[,c('b', 'c') := NULL] # works fine, but doesn't allow passing in of columns
```

The error is "Adding new column 'colsToDelete' then assigning NULL (deleting it)."  So clearly, it's interpreting 'colsToDelete' as a new column name.

The same issue occurs when doing something along these lines

```
dt[, colNames := lapply(.SD, adjustValue, y=factor), .SDcols = colNames]
```

I new to R, but rather more experienced with some other languages, so this may be a silly question.

Answer (score 69):

It's basically because we allow symbols on LHS of `:=` to add new columns, for convenience: ex: `DT[, col := val]`. So, in order to distinguish `col` itself being the name from whatever is stored in `col` being the column names, we check if the LHS is a `name` or an `expression`.

If it's a `name`, it adds the column with the name as such on the LHS, and if `expression`, then it gets evaluated.

```
DT[, col := val] # col is the column name.

DT[, (col) := val]  # col gets evaluated and replaced with its value
DT[, c(col) := val] # same as above
```

The preferred idiom is: `dt[, (colsToDelete) := NULL]`

HTH

Answer (score 23):

I am surprised no answer provided uses the `set()` function.

```
set(DT, , colsToDelete, NULL)
```

This should be the easiest.

Comment: two commas in a row?

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor The empty argument is the `i` argument, which refers to rows. As it's omitted, it indicates that **all** rows are to be updated.

Answer (score 14):

To extend on previous answer, you can delete columns by reference doing:

```
# delete columns 10 to 15
dt[ , (10:15) := NULL ]
```

or

```
# delete columns 3, 5 and 10 to 15
dt[ , (c(3,5,10:15)) := NULL ]
```

Comment: to add on this, you can also do                                                                   
      dt[ , -(10:15) ]  or dt[ , -c(3,5,10:15)]

Answer (score 0):

This code did the job for me. you need to have the position of the columns to be deleted e.g., `posvec` as mentioned in the `?set`

> j: Column name(s) (character) or number(s) (integer) to be assigned value
> when column(s) already exist, and only column name(s) if they are to
> be created.

```
DT_removed_slected_col = set(DT, j = posvec, value = NULL)
```

Also if you want to get the `posvec` you can try this:

```
selected_col = c('col_a','col_b',...)

selected_col = unlist(sapply(selected_col, function(x) grep(x,names(DT)))) 

namvec = names(selected_col) #col names

posvec = unname(selected_col) #col positions
```