# Updating data.table with get(x)

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following data.table

```
DT <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = 6:10, z = 11:15)
```

and I have a variable `a <- "y"`. I could access the values of `y` using `DT[, get(a)]`, no problem.

However, if I try to set the values of `y` to 0 using `DT[, get(a) := 0]`, I get the following error:

```
Error in get(a) : object 'y' not found
```

Why can't `get(a)` find `y` when using `:=`? How else could I update `y` without referencing it directly? This is useful if `a` is the argument of a function or I am iterating over a vector of variable names.

Answer: Well, it looks like `DT[, (a) := 0]`, `DT[, eval(a) := 0]`, `DT[, c(a) := 0]` all answer this question. Thanks to @eddi and @AnandaMahto for their help in the comments.

The best explanation of this issue is on this thread: [Removing multiple columns from r data table...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590341/removing-multiple-columns-from-r-data-table-with-parameter-for-columns-to-remove/24590543#24590543)

Comment: I suspect it's because `get(a)` inside a `data.table` operator returns something different than an object.  I've not used `data.table` so this may not be correct.

Comment: this is almost certainly a duplicate - the correct syntax for what you want is `DT[, (a) := 0]`

Comment: @eddi, is there much of a difference between what you wrote and `eval(a)` (which I was about to suggest but didn't because I'm posting from my phone right now).

Comment: @AnandaMahto the difference is typing an extra `eval` and also *doing* an extra `eval` internally (pretty unimportant as far as performance goes)

Comment: Thanks @eddi and Ananda, both your suggestions work. I understand this is a very basic question but I couldn't find it elsewhere. I'll post the answer and reference your comments.

Comment: Also here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24590543/403310